# Regarding length of chains of homogeneous primes

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $k$ be a field, and consider the polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. My question is this:

> Given a *homogeneous* ideal $I\subseteq (x_1,...,x_n)$, does every  maximal chain of *homogeneous* primes $I\subseteq p_0\subseteq\cdots\subseteq (x_1,...,x_n)$ have the same length?

I know the statement to be true if we consider all chains of primes between $I$ and $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and not only homogeneous ones, since the ring is catenary. But I'm not sure what happens in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $p_1\subset p_2$ are homogeneous prime ideals and no homogeneous prime lies in between, then no prime ideal lies in between.